# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null while integration of razorpay to react-native

Tags: android, react-native, razorpay

I had installed the react-native-razorpay package using

$ npm i react-native-razorpay --save

I have imported the RazorpayCheckout on the top:

import RazorpayCheckout from "react-native-razorpay";

then I have created a function named paymentRazor, which has been called to an onPress functionality of a button.

```
const paymentRazor = () => {

var options = {
  key: "rzp_test_Rh5hj15XBv8XmI",
  currency: "INR",
  amount: "5000",
  order_id: "order_DslnoIgkIDL8Zt",
  name: "Akul varshney",
  description: "Payment for purchase order",
  image: "http://103.107.67.49/static/media/Orane-Consulting-logo.c3a9713e.jpg",
  prefill: {
    email: "akul.varshney@orane.in",
    contact: "8800252885",
    name: "Akul Varshney",
  },
  theme: { color: "#53a20e" },
};

console.log(options);

RazorpayCheckout(options)
  .then((data) => {

    let bodyData = {
      razorpay_payment_id: data.razorpay_payment_id,
      razorpay_order_id: "order_DslnoIgkIDL8Zt",
      razorpay_signature: data.razorpay_signature,
    };
    dispatch(razorPayment(bodyData));
    alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
  })

  .catch((error) => {
    // handle failure
    alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Once I click on that button, the following error occurs:

LOG [TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null]

I tried the above method but when clicked on the button the open gets undefined.

Comment: What uses a variable called `open`? It could be library code.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall app from your mobile
and
npm  start --reset-cache